# Storing Paragraph into database using PHP without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an index.php page that contains a paragraph element & an input button:

```
<p id="result">Hello this is test paragraph</p>    
<input id="insertbutton" type="button" value="insert" />
```

I would like to store the paragraph content into database without refreshing the page when I click the insert button..

Hope I can get help

Thank you very much

Comment: Please show us what so far you tried.

Comment: use ajax of javascript or jQuery

Comment: You have to read about [Synchronous and asynchronous requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Ajax with jQuery to make a post request like this should be enough.

```
$("#insertbutton").click(function(){
    var data = "text=" + $("#result").text();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "post.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(){
            alert("success");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: insertbutton is selector , use #

Comment: This helped me very much, but it is inserting empty record. This is my php code:
<?php



$data = $_POST['data'];

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("db1", $connection);

$query = mysql_query("insert into test (QrCode) values ('$data')", $connection);

?>

any Idea??

Comment: $_POST['data'] should be $_POST['text'] , instead of changing the PHP code you can change the Javascript and replace "text" string with "data":  var data = "data=" + $("#result").text();

Comment: you are the best man, thank you very much ! it is entering records now

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="result">Hello this is test paragraph</p>

<input id="insertbutton" type="button" value="insert" />
```

//AJAX

```
$("#insertbutton").click(function(){
var dataToPass=$("#result").html();

$.ajax({
url:'Your_PHP_File_URL_that_will_do_insertion',
data:dataToPass
});
})
```